# Using random_split() pytorch over a folder containing multiple subfolders

Tags: python, pytorch

So, I have this folder which contains other folders, taken from ImageNet (e.g., one with images of butterflies, one with images with flowers and so on).

Now, I need to train a NN but I need to split the data in 3 sets: train, validation and test. I've seen that there is random_split() in pytorch and I tried to use it iterating over the "bigger" folder. Because obviously I don't want to do this manually for each subfolder.

I did a for cicle over the folder, with os.listdir - which I used to calculate how many pics there were in each subfolder - but I always get the error

`Sum of input lengths does not equal the length of the input dataset!`

But I don't know how to fix it.

The code I came up with so far is this:

```
import os
from torch.utils.data import random_split

path = '/Users/francesca/Documents/Tesi/imagenet/'

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith('.'):
        continue
    if files.endswith('.ipynb'):
        continue
    else:
        n_img = len(os.path.join(path, file))
        trlen = int(n_img * train_ratio)
        vllen = int(n_img * val_ratio)
        tslen = n_img - vllen - trlen
        tr, vl, ts = random_split(file, lengths = [trlen, vllen, tslen])
        trfnames.append(tr)
        vlfnames.append(vl)
        tsfnames.appned(ts)
        
print(trfnames)
```

And most likely it's wrong.

So the question is: how do I use random_split over a folder with subfolders, without creating a CustomDataset?

Thanks to anyone answering

Answer (score 0):

There is a Python package called split-folders that you could use. You can use it if you don't need to strictly use only PyTorch package.

```
pip install split-folders

import split_folders # or import splitfolders
input_folder = "/path/to/input/folder" #path of your input folder
output = "/path/to/output/folder" ##where you want the split datasets saved. one will be created if it does not exist or none is set

split_folders.ratio(input_folder, output=output, seed=42, ratio=(.8, .1, .1)) ## ratio of split are in order of train/val/test. You can change to whatever you want. For train/val sets only, you could do .75, .25 for example.
```

Comment: Yeah I've used that, but the sum of the images of the single folders split does not match the images I have without splitting. So the split-folders does not work. That's why I tried to use random_split